# Modify footer used by elsarticle.cls

Tags: header-footer, document-classes, elsarticle

I would like to modify the footer used by Elsevier's [`elsarticle.cls`](http://www.elsevier.com/framework_authors/misc/elsarticle.cls) without editing the class file directly.  I would like to eliminate the footer on the first page that states "Preprint submitted to Elsevier" (or the journal you specify with the optional `\journal{}` command).  Obviously I can just delete it from the class file but this change won't carry over to others without me providing an explicit modification of the class file.  I tried adding the modified lines of the class file to my `.tex` before the documentclass declaration, but they are ignored:

```
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape
% line below modified from elsarticle.cls
 \ifx\@journal\@empty Elsevier
\else\@journal\fi\hfill\today}%
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\documentclass{elsarticle}
```

Is there any way to remove that footer without editing the `.cls` file?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that displays the current behaviour.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have put your definition *before* the call to elsarticle, so the newer one overrode the older one.  You need to change the order of definitions!

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
\begin{document}     
\title{Paper}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for.  I also didn't know about using the \makeatletter and \makeatother commands, so many thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the feedback. I had been trying to remove the "Preprint Submitted to" line by modifying the .cls file but could not get the changes to make effect either.

Comment: Great answer! Is there any way I can keep the date on the first page, though?

Comment: @pawel Just add the date to the footer: `\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{\hfill\thepage}
 \def\@evenfoot{\thepage\hfill}}
\makeatother`

Answer (score 24):

Or you can replace the preprint footnotes with page number, so as to make the first page footnote style consistent with the following pages. To achieve this, simply:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{\centerline{\thepage}}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Great answer! Is there any way I can keep the date, though?

Answer (score 6):

You could try the following code, which uses the instruction `\patchcmd` provided by the `etoolbox` package. (What the code does is to replace the long argument of the definition of `@oddfoot` with `\relax`...)

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@pprintTitle}{\footnotesize\itshape
       Preprint submitted to \ifx\@journal\@empty Elsevier
       \else\@journal\fi\hfill\today}{\relax}{}{}
\makeatother
[rest of preamble]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the "elsarticle.cls" file and comment out the following lines

```
% \def\ps@pprintTitle{%
%      \let\@oddhead\@empty
%      \let\@evenhead\@empty
%      \def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape
%       Preprint submitted to \ifx\@journal\@empty Elsevier
%       \else\@journal\fi\hfill} %\today}%
%      \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

Comment: Do not change an original class file. Copy it to `myclass.cls` and change this file. Better way: to patch the original class file in your own tex file ...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to you can keep the date and make the title page unnumbered.

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
    \let\@oddhead\@empty
    \let\@evenhead\@empty
    \def\@oddfoot{\centerline{\hspace*{\fill} \raggedright \today} }%
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\journal{}

\setcounter{page}{0}
```