# The following template without the name of the journal and date

Tags: document-classes

How to keep all the features in this template but remove the Elsevier and date at the bottom of pages.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{\textbf{what and why}


\begin{abstract}
this is abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\hspace{-0.5cm} social epistemology, testimony, manipulation, truth, knowledge
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{\textbf{what and why}} %<- Added } here (forgotten)


\begin{abstract}
this is abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\hspace{-0.5cm} social epistemology, testimony, manipulation, truth, knowledge
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35714/120578 (possible duplicate)